# MySQL: Insert new record using MAX value of a column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to `INSERT` a new record, using the `MAX` value of the position column plus one, in the newly inserted row. So if the `MAX` value is 14, the next inserted row's position column value should be 15.

This is my current code, which is working but it needs 2 separate queries:

```
# get position order
$sql = 'SELECT MAX(position) FROM store_item_photo WHERE id_item = 3';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$position = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$position++;

# photo: new record
$sql = 'INSERT INTO store_item_photo (id_item, position) VALUES (3, :position)';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':position', $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I wanted to know if there is some way to achieve the same result with just one query:

```
# photo: new record (one query)
$sql = 'INSERT INTO store_item_photo (id_item, position) VALUES (3, (SELECT MAX(position) FROM store_item_photo WHERE id_item = 3) + 1)';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

That test is throwing an error. Is it possible to achieve this with a similar approach?

I built the schema in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/228058/1

Comment: Clue: insert into x(a,b,c) select a,b,c from y; - but note the usual caveats about storing derived data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a subquery in an Insert you don't have to use `VALUES`

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO store_item_photo (id_item, position)
  SELECT
    3 AS id_item,
    MAX(position) + 1
  FROM store_item_photo 
  WHERE id_item = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query :

```js
$sql = 'INSERT INTO store_item_photo (id_item, position) VALUES (3, ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM store_item_photo WHERE id_item = 3) + 1))';
$stmt = cnn()->query($sql);
```

Comment: Hi! That's the very same query i posted, not working.